# In Eclipse, how do I limit the Open Type shortcut to only show source files in my current project

Tags: java, eclipse, ide, shortcut

I have multiple games and when I am working on these games I often use the Open Type shortcut to find my classes, however every time I use it, all classes in the workspace of the name show up. Since I have multiple games, when I want to search for the `Player` class, for example, multiple Player classes show up and often times the one I am looking for is not the top.

Is there anyway to change this so that it only shows the files from the selected project or even to just show the ones from the current or most recent project first?

All help is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Create a Working Set from which to search:

1. Open the Open Type dialog.
2. Click on the arrow in the upper right.
3. Choose 'Select Working Set' -> New.
4. From there you can choose what you wish to add to the working set...a Project, a package, certain classes, etc...

Of course, you will have to change this working set depending upon where you wish to search. [Further information](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2Fconcepts%2Fcworkset.htm)